# VSCode: How do I enable the smart suggestions that include parameters, i.e "box.addEventListener(type, listener)"?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-snippets

Going through an E6 refresher course, for which I and the tutor are both using Visual Studio code. Now, in the video Visual Studio Code IntelliSense autocompletes the tutors code as per below:

[image: desired autocomplete suggestion]

```
box.addEv[tab]
```

IntelliSense Suggestions:

- **addEv**entlistener(type, listener)    *EventTarget*
- description-EventTarget.**addEv**entlistener()
- lo**ad**en**d**

and when the tutor hits ´tab´ it autocompletes and moves his course to ´type´ automatically with ´type´ ready to be overwritten with what event-type is needed (`click` in this case):

[image: desired autocomplete result]

```
box.addEventlistener(type, listener)
```

However, I only get the following suggestions from intelliSense:

- **addEv**entlistener

Which, if chosen simply autocompletes the code to:

```
box.addEventlistener
```

I've gone through the different snippet extensions for Javascript and ES6 and while they add snippet-autocompletion, for example, the javascript-snippets extensios adds :

`[ae]`
autocompletes to:

```
addEventListener
${1:document}.addEventListener('${2:event}', function(e) {
    ${0:// body...}
});
```

I haven't found a way to enable autocompletion as described above.

Is it a configuration? extension? custom snippets perhaps?

Comment: Not it, or at least it doesn't give the desired functionality.

Comment: Are you sure? It does for me: https://i.imgur.com/dvibPn9.gifv (that's with `"javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls"` enabled).

Comment: hmm, let me retry that once i get back from lunch on a fresh VSCode install

Comment: Using a fresh VSCode install, i can now confirm it works in a *.js file but not in a script-block in a HTML file.